# What C library version does my system use?

Tags: c, version, shared-library

How can I tell for sure what userland C library my system uses?  Possible reasons to need this information include:

- There's a gigantic source package I am considering downloading which I'm sure will do proper checks and lists a mininum library version, but I'd rather save myself a potential hassle by checking first if it will work.
- I am concerned about [ABI compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code_compatibility) with some third party binaries I want to try and install outside the system's package management system.
- I have a source package who's documentation mentions the need for a minimum version of my system's library, but the build process does not perform any checks.
- I am building a cross-compiler targeting a specific system and do not want to risk [forward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility) problems.

Comment: Why not try it and see. I don't know if the version tells you everything; what about patches? Or are distrubutions careful about altering the ABI? Isn't the issue whether the exported symbols are resolved, or something like that?

Comment: Nice answers, but no one addresses how to do this on a Mac, where there is no `ldd`. I'm not sure if `otool --version` can be regarded as giving the same information.

Comment: @dubiousjim Someone could; just not me, because I'm not a Mac user.  Around here you might have to ask specifically about that -- part of the issue is perhaps people generally don't use plain C much on OSX?  But I'm sure there will be a regular who knows.   You could also post a link to this in chat and see what happens, but probably a new, more specific question would be better.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**GNU/Linux systems** usually use either glibc (Fedora/Redhat family, Arch) or its close cousin, eglibc (Debian/Ubuntu family); since eglibc is now being merged back into glibc ([see *EGLIBC 2.19 Branch Created* under "News"](http://www.eglibc.org/home)), in the near future they will all be glibc again.

The easiest way to check the exact version is to ask `ldd`, which ships with the C library.

On Fedora 20:

```
> ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.18
```

That's glibc 2.18.

On Raspbian (Debian 7 port for ARMv6 Broadcom SoC):

```
> ldd --version
ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+rpi2) 2.13
```

That's eglibc 2.13.

If for whatever reason you have mixed and matched some parts or otherwise aren't sure about `ldd`, you can query the C library directly.

```
> whereis libc.so
libc: /usr/lib64/libc.a /usr/lib64/libc.so /usr/share/man/man7/libc.7.gz
```

None of those is executable but they provide a clue about where to find one.

```
> $(find /usr/lib64/ -executable -name "*libc.so*") --version
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.18, by Roland McGrath et al.
```

However, it is not necessarily so easy, because the C library does not have to reside somewhere `whereis` can find it.

```
> whereis libc.so
libc: /usr/share/man/man7/libc.7.gz
```

Unfortunately, the man page does not provide a version number.  `ldd` still comes in handy, since any working, dynamically linked executable on the system (e.g., almost everything in `/usr/bin`) will link to the C library.

```
> ldd /usr/bin/touch
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so (0xb6eed000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0xb6ed0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6da1000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6efb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6d82000)
```

`libc.so.6` is on the third line.

```
> /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 --version
GNU C Library (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+rpi2) stable release version 2.13, by Roland McGrath et al.
```

Comment: What makes a GNU/Linux system "normal"? What about [distributions](http://wiki.musl-libc.org/wiki/Projects_using_musl) using [musl](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It was intended to apply to GNU/Linux, as in, "normal GNU/Linux" (adjective, noun), since there could be (are, I'm sure) systems which *do not* use (e)glibc but *do* use the rest of the GNU stack (bash, binutils, etc.).  I would consider those "unusual" GNU/Linux systems.  But I've removed the "normal " and changed it to "GNU/Linux systems *usually* use...".  Note I intentionally left the *question* open WRT OS specifics (there is no linux or GNU or glibc tag), so if you want to add an answer regarding any system appropriate to U&L, please do.

Comment: After I found it like you showed and I queried the version, it also printed available extensions! (in my case stubs, crypt, libidn, native threads and bind) and referred to ABI: libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC.

Comment: Debian uses `/lib/\`uname -m\`*` path. So portable way would be: `find /lib/\`uname -m\`* /usr/lib* -executable -name "*libc.so*" | xargs --version`. Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: @pevik: Wrong, on arm it's /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6, and not /lib/armv7l/libc.so.6

Comment: @Quandary: thanks for info. Any idea, how to genererate `arm-linux-gnueabihf`?

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to find it on android for Bionic.

Answer (score 15):

A system isn't actually limited to one C library. Most, though, primarily use only one, which will also be the one the default compiler uses. And since you're downloading source code to compile, that's the one you're concerned with.

Start with a trivial program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

compile it using the compiler you're going to use for the source code, then use `ldd` to find out where the C library is:

```
$ ldd ./libc-test 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff2e5fe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8c8ad98000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8c8b171000)
```

You now have the path to the C library. You could look this up in your package manager to find the package (e.g., `dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` or `rpm -q -f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`).

At least in the case of eglibc/glibc, you can run it:

```
$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6  
GNU C Library (Debian EGLIBC 2.18-4) stable release version 2.18, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
⋮
```

Finally, you could see if you can get clues from `objdump -p  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, by looking in the *version definitions* section:

```
Version definitions:
1 0x01 0x0865f4e6 libc.so.6
2 0x00 0x09691a75 GLIBC_2.2.5
3 0x00 0x09691a76 GLIBC_2.2.6
⋮
21 0x00 0x06969197 GLIBC_2.17
        GLIBC_2.16 
22 0x00 0x06969198 GLIBC_2.18
        GLIBC_2.17 
23 0x00 0x0963cf85 GLIBC_PRIVATE
        GLIBC_2.18
```

Note how the GLIBC_2.18 symbol has the most recent version number among the symbols listed, and the library version is indeed 2.18. It's eglibc, though (it aims to be binary-compatible with glibc 2.18, so it uses the same symbol versions).

You could also attempt to use `strings` to find out something about it. You'll want to specify a longer minimal length (`-n`), or use grep to search for something:

```
$ strings  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep 'version [0-9]'
$ strings  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep -iC1 'copyright'
```

both work for this eglibc.

NOTE: The Debian package utility `dpkg-shlibdeps` uses `objdump` under the hood, along with stored symbol information in Debian library packages to determine the minimum versions of dependencies required by binary Debian packages at build time. Basically, it looks at the symbols exported by the binary Debian package, and then finds the minimum versions of the libraries that contain those symbols.

Answer (score 10):

The obvious answer, though not the most comprehensive, is to check your package manager, e.g

```
rpm -qi glibc
dpkg -l libc6
```

(Sadly, glibc doesn't have a pkconfig `.pc` file, so `pkgconfig --modversion glibc` is a non-runner.) See also  @Gnouc's excellent `getconf` suggestion.

The simplest case, with gcc+glibc, and the one I mostly use first is to just execute `libc.so`, as outlined in some of the other answers here. There's no need to pass any arguments, it outputs its version by default. This works back as far as glibc-2.1 (glibc-2.0 seg-faults, though way back then you could check the (now retired) `glibcbug` script to confirm the version). This method also works with recent (>0.9.15) versions of [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) (which just went 1.0 today, March 20th). It does not work with uClibc, it segfaults.

One simple way to tell exactly what your `gcc` is going to do is compile:

```
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%s %s\n",gnu_get_libc_version(),gnu_get_libc_release());
    printf("glibc v%i %i.%i\n",__GNU_LIBRARY__,__GLIBC__,__GLIBC_MINOR__);
    return 0;
}
```

(with glibc, `<stdio.h>` includes `<features.h>` which defines the relevant GLIBC macros, you need `<gnu/libc-version.h>` for the function declarations.)

This catches more complex cases (multiple libc's, and/or multiple compilers), assuming you're using the right compiler (and flags) of course. (I suspect it won't distinguish between eglibc and glibc proper though.)

<strike>If you are certain you are using glibc (or eglibc) then `ld` will also confirm the version</strike> (sorry, this is not correct).

If `__GNU_LIBRARY__` is not defined you will get errors, then it's time for plan B.

`gcc -dumpmachine` may help, e.g. for uclibc it has a `-uclibc` suffix, as may `gcc -dumpspecs | grep dynamic-linker`. This also may imply the ABI.

`gcc -print-file-name=libc.so` will tell you what file the compiler will use for "`-lc`", this is almost certainly a linker-script within your gcc installation, which you can read it as plain text. That will show the exact path to `libc.so`. This will also work if you're passing flags like `-m32` or `-m64`.

In the event you're using [uclibc](http://www.uclibc.org/) (as used by OpenWRT and more), it defines `__UCLIBC_MAJOR__`, `__UCLIBC_MINOR__` and `__UCLIBC_SUBLEVEL__` as well as `__UCLIBC__` in `<features.h>`, so it's easily detected using a minor variation on the above C code snippet. In the interest of compatibility, uClibc may also define the GNU/GLIBC macros as used above, it currently pretends to be glibc-2.2. It does not currently implement the `gnu_get_libc_X()` functions, but it *does* implement `getconf` which may also mislead (I suspect it returns an empty answer for `getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION`, my build env is sulking today so I cannot confirm.)

In the unlikely event you're using [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/), running `diet -v` will display the version.

(FWIW, over several years with software using autoconf I've had more problems with unchecked-for `gcc` and `g++` requirements than with checked-for glibc features.)

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get it:

```
getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION
```

Comment: Nice one, this *should* work reliably since glibc-2.3.3.

Answer (score 5):

GNU libc (what most Linux distributions use in one form or the other) goes to great lengths to keep strict backwards compatibility. So you should run into trouble only if you try to run a too-new binary on an old version (or a "enterprise" distribution, they normally freeze versions, particularly foundation ones like the C library, backporting fixes while keeping rigurous binary compatibility). I believe you are much more liable to run into problems with other libraries (C++ had a few API/ABI changes in recent memory, some other libraries just *don't* care for backward compatibility).

Sadly, the only way to find out for sure is to try.

Comment: +1 In fact they have [a chart regarding backward compatibility](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7G7TX.png) and I would assume the only reason it isn't all 100% is because of code that exploits esoteric GNU extensions.  However, there's no such chart I'm aware of regarding **forward compatibility**, which as you note is more the real concern.

Answer (score 5):

(This is essentially the same as goldilocks' answer but with some more explanation of what is going on under the hood.)

The core shared library for GNU libc, `libc.so.6` (on Linux; Hurd has a different SONAME), has the unusual property (for shared libraries) that you can invoke it as an executable.  If you do, it prints out the sort of thing GNU utilities usually print when run with `--version`, like this:

```
$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
GNU C Library (Debian EGLIBC 2.18-4) stable release version 2.18, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.8.2.
Compiled on a Linux 3.12.6 system on 2014-03-02.
Available extensions:
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

But of course the directory where `libc.so.6` lives is not in `$PATH`, so you have to know where to look for it.  It might be in `/lib`, `/lib64`, `/usr/lib`, or something even wackier (as in this case).  Conveniently, `ldd` will tell you:

```
$ ldd /bin/sh | grep libc
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5660b93000)
```

For that to work, of course, you have to know the full pathname of a dynamically-linked binary executable.  The `sh` executable is guaranteed to be in `/bin` (because so many `#!` scripts expect it to be), and can't itself be a `#!` script.  It *could* be statically linked, but I haven't encountered a system that did that in many years.

I don't know what you do if you're running with uClibc or musl or something more exotic.

Comment: Well, you don't *have* to know the full path to /bin/sh or whatever. You can always `$ ldd $(which sh) | grep libc`. :D